# What does "ever" mean in comparative constructions?

Tags: comparison

> [i]
>
> As I matured and the protective cartilage at the ends of my bones wore away, as cartilage tends to do, the pain became more acute. And yet, instead of complaining, I tried to hide my problem. Perhaps I have always been more like Eve than I’ve ***ever*** admitted, for I distrusted the medical world immensely, and I found ways to compensate for my disability so I could avoid a diagnosis that would undoubtedly hasten my demise.
>   (Garth Stein, The Art of Racing in the Rain)
>
> [ii]
>
> It is better than it has ***ever*** been. (CGEL, p144)

[CGEL](http://www.cambridge.org/uk/linguistics/cgel/) says, in [ii] “*the comparison is between its quality now and its quality at any time within the time-span –– clearly the potential for it to be of such and such a quality still exists*”. From this, I guessed the meaning of *ever* was *at any time within the time-span*. But after having consulted [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/ever), it seems like *ever* might just be an intensifier in comparative constructions, having lost the said meaning.

Which way should I understand *ever* in these constructions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t think they’re mutually exclusive. The emphasis in OALD’s second meaning seems to derive from a direct extension of the primary “at any time” sense, though it ranges into the realm of the non-literal by exaggerating something in a way all involved know may not be a perfectly exact comparison between the current event and all times before.